# Kolmogorov complexity of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, kolmogorov-complexity

I've read that Kolmogorov comlexity is about calculating the least number of bits needed to describe a string or other mathematical objects.

Does 'other mathematical objects' include algorithms too?

I guess the answer is yes. But the thing that concerns me is how an algorithm defined in this context? Because  many algorithms do the exact same thing but do it differently. So they are not the same algorithms, also you can add a comment to an algorithm or change it in a way that the even though its text has changed the computations that happen are exactly the same. And they should be considered the same. so how is an algorithm defined in this context (if it is studied in the first place)?

Comment: An algorithm is a string !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithms are to be understood as Turing Machines, in the majority of contexts. But you are right: from a Turing Machine, one can always modify the transition table so that the Turing Machine we obtain is different, yet it essentially does the same thing. In this context, we say that the two Turing Machines have the same language: on any input, if one accepts the input then so does the other one and the output is the same.

But this doesn't change the definition: given an algorithm (a Turing Machine) $N$, the Kolmogorov complexity of $N$ is the smallest size of pairs $(M,w)$ where $M$ is a Turing machine and $w$ is a word in the alphabet of $M$ so that on input $w$, $M$ outputs $N$ on its tape.

Comment: thank you. but by your definition 2 algorithms might have different efficiencies but be equivalent, how can that get fixed? can you give an equivalence relation such that 2 machines are equivalent when they do the same "internal" operations as well as having the "same input $\Longrightarrow$ same output" property.

Comment: There are many algorithms that sort lists of integers, and they have different complexity. But they are still sorting algorithms!

Comment: yes but not the same sorting algorithms. they are definitely different so they are not the same algorithms

Comment: This is debatable, but I think it is not the subject of your initial question. Whether an algorithm is equivalent to another one has nothing to do with Kolmogorov complexity.

Comment: If by an algorithm we simply mean a turing machine then we can represent it using a string. but that is not very useful. because many turing machines do the same internal operations(let alone external). but if we mean by an algorithm just a function that gets some input and produces some output then efficiency changes. then again it is not usefull. suppose I have an algorithm that is long and i want to make it shorter, without losing its efficiency.

Comment: Kolmogorov complexity is not about efficiency, hence it is not the tool you are looking for to distinguish Turing Machines, that's all.

Comment: so the answer to my first question is no. thanks.

Comment: Was the first question "Does 'other mathematical objects' include algorithms too?"? If so, the answer is yes! But Kolmogorov complexity is not about computational complexity, and I cannot emphasize this more.

Comment: you are right. They are studied but with a different point of view, not my point of view. thank you anyway.